# Ignore ssl certs for easy install python

Tags: python, ssl, pip, dependencies, easy-install

I have my lib which has setup as

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    setup_requires=['pbr>=0.11.0'],
    pbr=True
)
```

**setup.cfg**

```
[metadata]
name = MyLib

[options]
zip_safe = False
include_package_data = True
install_requires =
    cython
    pyrex
    pymssql
    elementtree
    bleach
    BeautifulSoup4
    pytz
    MySQL_python
    retry
    elementtree
    Pyrex
dependency_links =
    https://pypi.mydomain.com/packages/

[files]
packages =
    MyLib
    MyLib.package1
    MyLib.package1.new1

[tool:wheel]
universal = 1

[flake8]
exclude =
    venv,
    .tox,
    .git,
    __pycache__,
    *.pyc,
    *.egg-info,
    .cache,
    .eggs,
max-line-length = 80

[tool:pytest]
testpaths=MyLib/tests
ignore=
    .tox
    .cache
    docs
    config.py
    venv

[coverage:run]
omit=
    MyLib/config.py
```

I am using this `MyLib` in my application `requirements.txt`

**myapp/requirements.txt**
...
...
MyLib==1.2.3
...
...

When I installed, with `/usr/local/pyenv/versions/myapp/bin/pip install -i https://pypi.mydomain.com --trusted-host pypi.mydomain.com -r /opt/school/apps/myapp/requirements.txt`, it was redirecting to `pypi.python.org`. Then I get that `easy_install` is using another config as `~/.pydistutils.cfg`. I added as

**~/.pydistutils.cfg**

```
[easy_install]
index_url=https://pypi.mydomain.com/
find_links = https://pypi.mydomain.com/simple/
allow_hosts = pypi.mydomain.com
```

Now its not redirecting to `pypi.python.org` but it gives error for SSL.

```
/usr/local/pyenv/versions/myapp/bin/pip install -i https://pypi.mydomain.com --trusted-host pypi.mydomain.com -r /opt/school/apps/myapp/requirements.txt
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs==1.4.3 in /usr/local/pyenv/versions/2.7.13/envs/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /opt/school/apps/myapp/requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /usr/local/pyenv/versions/2.7.13/envs/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /opt/school/apps/myapp/requirements.txt (line 2))
Requirement already satisfied: bleach==2.0.0 in /usr/local/pyenv/versions/2.7.13/envs/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /opt/school/apps/myapp/requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied: click==6.7 in /usr/local/pyenv/versions/2.7.13/envs/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r /opt/school/apps/myapp/requirements.txt (line 4))
Collecting MyLib==1.2.3 (from -r /opt/school/apps/myapp/requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading https://pypi.mydomain.com/packages/MyLib-1.2.3.tar.gz (221kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 225kB 31.8MB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Download error on https://pypi.mydomain.com/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661) -- Some packages may not be found!
    Download error on https://pypi.mydomain.com/pbr/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661) -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'pbr' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.mydomain.com/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661) -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or working download links found for pbr>=0.11.0
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-Lsc4UJ/MyLib/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        pbr=True
      File "/usr/local/pyenv/versions/2.7.13/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/pyenv/versions/2.7.13/envs/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 315, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/usr/local/pyenv/versions/2.7.13/envs/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/local/pyenv/versions/2.7.13/envs/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 850, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/usr/local/pyenv/versions/2.7.13/envs/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1122, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/local/pyenv/versions/2.7.13/envs/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1134, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/local/pyenv/versions/2.7.13/envs/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 429, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/local/pyenv/versions/2.7.13/envs/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 659, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pbr>=0.11.0')

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Lsc4UJ/MyLib/
```

1. Is there any way to force `dependency_links` not to use `~/.pydistutils.cfg` ?

If answer of `1` is NO, then how to ignore SSL for my pypi server?

**Tried the solution given below.**

```
# /usr/local/pyenv/versions/myapp/bin/python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-9.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.1
Successfully installed pip-18.0

/usr/local/pyenv/versions/myapp/bin/pip install -i https://pypi.mydomain.com --trusted-host pypi.mydomain.com -r /opt/school/apps/myapp/requirements.txt
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.mydomain.com
Collecting MyLib==1.2.3 (from -r /opt/school/apps/myapp/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://pypi.mydomain.com/packages/MyLib-1.2.3.tar.gz (221kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 225kB 21.2MB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Download error on https://pypi.mydomain.com/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661) -- Some packages may not be found!
    Download error on https://pypi.mydomain.com/pbr/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661) -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'pbr' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.mydomain.com/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661) -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or working download links found for pbr>=0.11.0
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-JD4AuE/MyLib/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        pbr=True
      File "/usr/local/pyenv/versions/2.7.13/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/pyenv/versions/cvcollect/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 315, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/usr/local/pyenv/versions/cvcollect/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/local/pyenv/versions/cvcollect/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 850, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/usr/local/pyenv/versions/cvcollect/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1122, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/local/pyenv/versions/cvcollect/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1134, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/local/pyenv/versions/cvcollect/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 429, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/local/pyenv/versions/cvcollect/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 659, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pbr>=0.11.0')

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-JD4AuE/MyLib/
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4205) is,

> setuptools is trying to talk to PyPI, not pip,
>   and that 3.6.0 on macOS does not have access to a CA Bundle by default
>   and setuptools doesn't bundle one like pip does. You'll need to
>   install something like certifi or raise an issue with setuptools.

You can force install new version of pip,

```
curl 'https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py' > get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

You can also try installing [certifi](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/) as mentioned in the above issue,

```
pip install certifi
```

> Certifi is a carefully curated collection of Root Certificates for
>   validating the trustworthiness of SSL certificates while verifying the
>   identity of TLS hosts. It has been extracted from the Requests
>   project.

TLS can be disabled using `--trusted-host`, but it is **dangerous** and not recommend at all.

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org pip --upgrade
```

Comment: Sufiyan, I tried on `Cent OS 6.X`, there also it gives same error. Its not specific to MacOS.

Comment: Sufiyan, I tried the solution, but still its same issue

Comment: Sifiyan, let me know if you have any other thoughts on this.

Comment: have you tried installing `incremental`? `pip install incremental`, or uninstalling and re-installing openssl?

Comment: please also try changing mirror, https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4205#issuecomment-382154209